# Packaging to deb : no source format specified in debian/source/format

Tags: package-management, 15.10

Am following the tutorial explained [here](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/packaging-new-software.html) to build a deb file for my own software. The Software itself will be distributed as deb file in our website and so no need to put on PPA or something like that for now. Each time I build it, it fails. I don't understand the error as I can clearly see the format file is `3.0 (quilt)` (which was generated automatically)

Can anyone help me understand what is exactly going on here?

Here is the full error

```
~ bzr builddeb -- -us -uc
Building using working tree
Building package in normal mode
Purging the build dir: /home/stefano/Installer/Linux/deb/build-area/hosanna-studio-1.0
Looking for a way to retrieve the upstream tarball
Upstream tarball already exists in build directory, using that
Building the package in /home/stefano/Installer/Linux/deb/build-area/hosanna-studio-1.0, using debuild -us -uc
 dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc
dpkg-buildpackage: source package hosanna-studio
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 1.0-1
dpkg-buildpackage: source distribution unstable
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by ******* <******>
 dpkg-source --before-build hosanna-studio-1.0
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture amd64
 fakeroot debian/rules clean
dh clean 
   dh_testdir
   dh_auto_clean
   dh_clean
 dpkg-source -b hosanna-studio-1.0
dpkg-source: warning: no source format specified in debian/source/format, see dpkg-source(1)
dpkg-source: info: using source format '1.0'
dpkg-source: info: building hosanna-studio using existing hosanna-studio_1.0.orig.tar.gz
dpkg-source: info: building hosanna-studio in hosanna-studio_1.0-1.diff.gz
dpkg-source: warning: ignoring deletion of file libcurl.so.4, use --include-removal to override
dpkg-source: warning: ignoring deletion of file libicudata.so.56, use --include-removal to override
dpkg-source: warning: ignoring deletion of file libcurl.so, use --include-removal to override
dpkg-source: warning: ignoring deletion of file libssl.so, use --include-removal to override
dpkg-source: warning: ignoring deletion of file libicuuc.so.56.1, use --include-removal to override
dpkg-source: warning: ignoring deletion of file libwxdatabase.so, use --include-removal to override
dpkg-source: warning: ignoring deletion of file libicuio.so.56, use --include-removal to override
dpkg-source: warning: ignoring deletion of file libicudata.so, use --include-removal to override
dpkg-source: warning: ignoring deletion of file libssh2.so.1, use --include-removal to override
dpkg-source: warning: ignoring deletion of file libcrypto.so, use --include-removal to override
dpkg-source: warning: ignoring deletion of file curl, use --include-removal to override
dpkg-source: warning: ignoring deletion of file libsdk.so, use --include-removal to override
dpkg-source: warning: ignoring deletion of file libgit2.so, use --include-removal to override
dpkg-source: warning: ignoring deletion of file libicuio.so.56.1, use --include-removal to override
dpkg-source: warning: ignoring deletion of file libicuuc.so.56, use --include-removal to override
dpkg-source: warning: ignoring deletion of file libicuuc.so, use --include-removal to override
dpkg-source: warning: ignoring deletion of file libicui18n.so.56, use --include-removal to override
dpkg-source: warning: ignoring deletion of file libicuio.so, use --include-removal to override
dpkg-source: warning: ignoring deletion of file libssl.so.1.1, use --include-removal to override
dpkg-source: warning: ignoring deletion of file libssh2.so.1.0.1, use --include-removal to override
dpkg-source: warning: ignoring deletion of file libgit2.so.0.23.0, use --include-removal to override
dpkg-source: warning: ignoring deletion of file libcurl.so.4.4.0, use --include-removal to override
dpkg-source: warning: ignoring deletion of file libgit2.so.23, use --include-removal to override
dpkg-source: warning: ignoring deletion of file Studio, use --include-removal to override
dpkg-source: warning: ignoring deletion of file libssh2.so, use --include-removal to override
dpkg-source: warning: ignoring deletion of file libicudata.so.56.1, use --include-removal to override
dpkg-source: warning: ignoring deletion of file libicui18n.so.56.1, use --include-removal to override
dpkg-source: warning: ignoring deletion of file libcrypto.so.1.1, use --include-removal to override
dpkg-source: warning: ignoring deletion of file libicui18n.so, use --include-removal to override
dpkg-source: warning: ignoring deletion of file libpelet.so, use --include-removal to override
dpkg-source: warning: ignoring deletion of directory plugins
dpkg-source: warning: ignoring deletion of file plugins/git_plugin.so, use --include-removal to override
dpkg-source: warning: ignoring deletion of file plugins/ftp_plugin.so, use --include-removal to override
dpkg-source: warning: newly created empty file 'debian/docs' will not be represented in diff
dpkg-source: error: cannot represent change to ftp_plugin.so: binary file contents changed
dpkg-source: error: cannot represent change to git_plugin.so: binary file contents changed
dpkg-source: unrepresentable changes to source
dpkg-buildpackage: error: dpkg-source -b hosanna-studio-1.0 gave error exit status 1
debuild: fatal error at line 1374:
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc failed
bzr: ERROR: The build failed.
```

Comment: Are you building the package from source? or just binary that you want to wrap it in deb?